# Ruby on Rails turn each iteration into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I feel like this is such an easy question

```
<% @state.cities.each do |city| %>
   <%= city.id %>
<% end %>
```

puts the ids as follows:

```
1
2
3 etc...
```

How do I turn the iteration into an array?

so it outputs as follows:

```
[1,2,3,4,etc...]
```

Comment: Why downvoting without explaining why ? Completely useless. If you think the question needs improvement or shouldn't be here, explain it to the OP so he/she learns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method that does just that!

What you are looking for is the `map` method.

> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map

The documentation states, creates an array containing the values returned by a block.

```
@state.map do |state|
  state.id
end
=> [1,2,3,...]
```

Which is the same as:

```
@state.map(&:id)
=> [1,2,3,...]
```

But uses the Ruby Enumerable shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
<%= @state.map(&:id) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`@state.map(&:id)` would give you the same result!